# Linq entity look ahead to value in next row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

When querying my entity framework DB, I am trying to match a condition based on the values from 2 rows.

My current query looks like this:

```
var query = context.table.where(x => x.row > 2);
```

This all works fine.

What I now want to achieve is to query the table based on the value in current and next row eg:

```
var query = context.table.where(x => x.row > 2 && x.row[next row up in DB] < 2);
```

Can this be done.

I know I can achieve this in code, but can it be done in a single query using LINQ and entity?

Here is an example of how I would do this with SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_Table p
INNER JOIN t_Table f
ON (p.id + 1) = f.id
WHERE p.column = whatever
AND f.column = whatever2
```

Comment: No, can't you download all the data and work with it in memory?

Comment: Define "next". Based on what (order)?

Comment: I can but that seems to me to be a poor option - what if it was an extremeley large table? Or what if this query was run many times? I could easily do this in SQL - this seems to be a big weakness of Entity - which I am becoming more and more disappointed with as time goes by

Comment: @IvanStoev yes based on order - can be anything for now - index etc - I am just trying to establish the principle

Comment: @Alex: How would you do this in SQL?

Comment: @JonathanWood I would make 2 joins onto the required table and then in my Where caluse I would say where >t1.col and <t2.col

Comment: EF is great for many things, and it provides lots of flexibility, but it's not even intended to replace all use cases for SqlCommand and the like.  And if you're talking about bulk operations or other taxing operations, you're probably going to care about your execution plans more, so crafting and tuning your own SQL makes sense.  EF is a great tool, but it's not always the right tool for the job at hand.

Comment: If your dbms supports something like MSSQL's `LEAD` or `LAG`, then you can skip the duplicative join, and using SqlDataReader to process the results will be about as performant as you can reasonably get.

Comment: @Alex You can do the same thing in EF/LINQ - can you show your SQL?

Comment: @NetMage I have added the SQL

Comment: Notice that it's logically impossible to do this in a single query/command, as you are trying to filter the content of the output **based on the content of the output itself**. That will inherently be a two step process: (step 1) generate the unfiltered dataset (step 2) filter the dataset according to its own data. You might be able to write a contrived SQL query that looks like it's a single query, but you'll inherently end up with a query (step 2) that relies on a subquery (step 1). Rows in a table should ideally be independent of each other, at the very least for retrieval purposes.

Comment: @Flater I don't think I would call a join / cross-join a sub-query?

Comment: @Alex I found a way to handle your inner join and it generates a join in SQL and seems to be faster, though it uses a sub-select for the math...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating your sample SQL into LINQ to SQL:

```
var ans = from p in t_table
          from f in t_table
          where (p.id+1) == f.id && p.column == whatever && f.column == whatever2
          select new { p, f };
```

This does not appear to generate an inner join in SQL but rather a cross-join, but I assume the SQL engine will handle it appropriately. Note that LINQ can only do equi-joins.

I didn't realize you can do (some) expressions in LINQ joins as long as equal is the primary operator, and this generates a sub-select and an inner join, which seems quite a bit faster:

```
var ans = from p in t_table
          where p.column == whatever
          let pidplus1 = p.id+1
          join f in t_table on pidplus1 equals f.id
          where f.column == whatever2
          select new { p, f };
```

Comment: the only issue I have found with this kind of join is that it can be extremeley slow on larger tables - almost unusably slow in some cases

Comment: I think it is as close as LINQ can come to your SQL, otherwise I think you will need to use SQL directly.

Comment: I agree - I think that is what I will do